# A question about Solvable Group.

Tags: group-theory

I have a solvable group $G$ with a $p$-sylow subgroup $P$ such that $C_G(P)=Z(G)$ and for every $q$-sylow subgroup $Q$ of $G$ where $q\neq p$, $Z(G)\lvertneqq C_G(Q)$. Now I want to prove that $P$ is not normal in $G$ and the other sylow subgroups are normal.
Any idea?
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: This question could be improved by including the context where you encountered the problem (what class, what textbook), and by including what you have tried already. That information makes it easier for others to write helpful answers. The site allows you to edit your question so it is easy to add additional information.

Comment: It seems to me that any nonabelian $p$-group is a counterexample. Less trivially, isn't ${\rm SL}_2(3)$ with $p=2$ a counterexample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G=P$ (is any non-abelian $p$-group) then you have a counterexample.

A less trivial counterexample is $G=\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$ of order 24 with $p=2$. Its Sylow 2-subgroup is $P=Q_8$, and its Sylow 3-subgroups $Q$ are all cyclic of order 3. The centralizer of $P$ is $Z(P) = Z(G)$, but of course the centralizer of $Q$ contains not only $Z(G)$ but also $Z(Q)=Q$. Contrary to your goals, $P$ is normal and $Q$ is not.

In case you got the normal versus not normal switched: the dihedral group of order 24 satisfies the hypothesis with $p=2$, but $Q$ is normal and $P$ is not.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that $G=P$ is only a counterexample when $P$ is nonabelian,since otherwise the condition on $q$ fails for all primes $q \ne p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: thanks, fixed!